# iOS Section Footer floating after keyboard is dismissed

Tags: ios5, uitableview

This issue has been driving me up the wall for the last few days. I am using NO custom classes, this has all been set up using Interface Builder

I have a Navigation View Controller which has 1 sub view: a Table View. I have set this up in xCode to be a static table with 1 section with a footer. The section contains some large cells each with 1 text field in them like the screenshot [image: normal screen] nothing fancy.

Now when I click on the text fields and dismiss the keyboard I end up with the footer left in the middle of the page like so [image: floating footer]

If I scroll the table in anyway the footer will go back to where its supposed to be. Is there anything I have overlooked/can do to fix this. Any insight on the matter will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I overcame this problem:

1. Create a new View Controller subclass.
2. Make it a UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate
3. Add a table view to your View Controller in IB (or the Storyboard).
4. Set the data source and delegate for this table view to your View Controller.

Your footer view should be in the correct place after dismissing the keyboard.

For whatever reason, having the table view inside a regular UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController meant that the footer properly re-positioned itself after dismissing the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think that this is a small bug in the UITableViewController

Comment: @Meberem That is not a bug, it's the way it is suppose to be for a UITableViewController.